# Creating bivariate normal distribution ellipse on plot that has log-transformed x and y axis

Tags: r, logging, plot, ellipse

Although i have found many answers on how to draw a bivariate normal distribution ellipse on an existing plot, i have a question regarding plotting this ellipse onto an existing plot for which the x- and y-axis are log-transformed.

As an example I have following data to which i add an ellipse

```
library(mixtools)
library(truncnorm)
x<-rtruncnorm(n=100, a=0, b=20)
y=1+.3*x+.3*rnorm(100)
data<-cbind(x,y)
mu <-c(mean(x), mean(y)) 
sigma <- var(data) 
plot(data)
ellipse(mu, sigma, alpha=0.1, npoints = 200, newplot = FALSE)
```

[image]

However, my actual data requires that i use log transformed x- and y-axis, as so

```
plot(data,log="xy")
```

When plotting the "ellipse" function, i no longer get an ellipse

```
ellipse(mu, sigma, alpha=0.1, npoints = 200, newplot = FALSE)
```

[image]

Adding "log" to the ellipse function specifications is also no option

```
ellipse(mu, sigma, alpha=0.1, npoints = 200, newplot = FALSE,log="xy")
```

Warning message:
    In plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
  "log" is not a graphical parameter.

Can someone help me out with this one?

Thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

Package `car` can handle ellipses in log-transformed space. Here is a taste of what it can do. One line is without the log argument while the almost full ellipse is with log argument.

```
library(car)
plot.default(data, log = "xy")
car::ellipse(center = log(mu), shape = sigma, radius = 3, center.pch = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, i would still like to specify an alpha value (as in mixtools:ellipse i can specify "alpha"). Is this also possible with the car:ellipse function? Furthermore, the "radius" specification in the car:ellipse function, is this arbitrary?

Comment: I would reckon you would have to calculate the correct `radius` which would already incorporate "`alpha`". This is probably more tricky on log transformed axis. If possible, I would avoid transforming the data altogether and use a model that can handle your data (mean, variance).